# I am trying to loop through data that is coming in from the front end

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I have data coming in through the front end to the back end method. Once the data comes in i need to loop through it and for each object output it to the text file. In the code snippet the `pi.GetValue(order)` returns the correct values. I need to access these values individually and input them into the text file. I am fairly new to C#. In the javascript world the syntax would be pi mapped to properties and then to access the values it would be `pi.CartNumber, pi.LineNumber,` etc..

I have tried the code that is shown and i have also tried using the `GetEnumerator()` method

```
Model:
public class OrderDetails
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CartNumber { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public int LineNumber { get; set; }
        public string PartNumber { get; set; }
        public int Qty { get; set; }
        public int SalesLocation { get; set; }
    }

Repository Method:

public async Task<OrderDetails> AddOrder(OrderDetails order)
        {
            await _context.OrderDetails.AddAsync(order);

            await SaveAll();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            PropertyInfo[] properties = order.GetType().GetProperties();

            var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(($"Y:\\WOL-0{order.CartNumber}-{order.CustomerId}-{date}-085715.txt")))
            {

                foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(pi.GetValue(order));

                    writer.WriteLine($"0{order.CartNumber}  {order.LineNumber}  {order.PartNumber}  {order.Qty} EA          {order.SalesLocation}   {order.SalesLocation}                                   EA                      Y                                                       ");

                }

            }


            return order;
        }
```

The expected result would be displaying multiple lines inside of the file when there are multiple inputs coming in from the data. The actual results is it writes 6 lines with the first thing it comes to in the data.

EDIT:

This is an example of one row.

```
45588   1   DEWDC385K   1   EA  228.4832        101 101                                 EA                      Y
```

Comment: `order` is only one instance and you are iterating over its properties. Don't think that is what you want. Do you mean to take a list of orders instead of a single instance?

Comment: I think so. The data is coming from the front end from a textarea. It includes Part numbers and qtys. When there are multiple lines in there the database inputs a row for each item they enter along with its quanity. When that is sent to the back end. i need to loop though it and for each line input it into the text file. Below is an example of how it should look.

Comment: This is an example of one row. I can get it to output that but when they put multiple items in and it creates multiple rows it will only grab one. There may be a better way to do this other than a loop but i am not aware of it.   I added an example row to my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) You do not need reflection (`pi`-stuff) here. (2) Your `AddOrder` method takes only single `OrderDetails`-object so you cannot do any looping.

**Update**: Actual problem was that there was only one single line of text in file despite of there were multiple `AddOrder`-calls subsequentally. I modified `StreamWriter` initialization and now it appends lines to file instead of clearing it before writing.

Below is simplified version of `AddOrder` where it handles OrderDetails-object and after succesful saving, writes record to file.

```
public class OrderDetails
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CartNumber { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public int SalesLocation { get; set; }
}

public async Task<OrderDetails> AddOrder(OrderDetails order)
{
    await _context.OrderDetails.AddAsync(order);
    await SaveAll();
    var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter($"Y:\\WOL-0{order.CartNumber}-{order.CustomerId}-{date}-085715.txt", true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine($"0{order.CartNumber}  {order.LineNumber}  {order.PartNumber}  {order.Qty} EA          {order.SalesLocation}   {order.SalesLocation}                                   EA                      Y                                                       ");        
    }
    return order;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and it works for one single row. Whenever the data coming in is more than one it will only grab the one row and i need it to grab them all

Comment: @JonathanEmery can you show that code which calls AddOrder-method?

Comment: ` [HttpPut]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrder(OrderDetails order)
        {
            await _repo.AddOrder(order);

            return Ok(order);
        }`

Comment: The "Order" is coming from the angular front end from a textarea and form.  Inside of the textarea whenever someone inputs multiple lines inside the textarea it gets appeneded to an array as an object. If there are multiple lines it spits out multiple arrays but it is send to the backend as an "Order". it is populating the database correctly as multiple rows. Here is an example of whats happning on the front end.

Comment: Input: MILS, 6   MISDJ, 7   Code that takes that and puts it into an object along with other fields              `outArr[outArr.length] = { 'cartNumber': this.cartNumber, 'partNumber': split[0], 'qty': split[1], 'customerId': this.customerInfoForm.customerId, 'lineNumber': index, 'salesLocation': this.customerInfoForm.salesLocationId };`

Comment: @JonathanEmery is it problem that there is only one text line in file? I modified answer: added true to StreamWriter ctor so text is appended to file and file is not cleared on every call.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!!

Comment: @JonathanEmery Good to hear!